# What's wrong in the sentence: "I think it best to be well-prepared for the exam"

Tags: grammaticality, ellipsis

Is there a flaw in the following sentence?

> I think it best to be well-prepared for the exam.

Should it become this?

> I think **that** it **is** best to be well-prepared for the exam.

I am a bit confused because I read this in a text where the author does not appear to have any grammatical (or spelling) errors except possibly this one.

Comment: In general, if you could also provide a source or a link, that might be helpful.

Comment: @Max I don't see why providing a source is necessary. Are you suggesting that it might depend on the context?

Comment: In general, the context is very helpful.

Comment: @Max thank you. I really forgot where I read this. I'll make sure to provide the context in the next time.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong or not understandable with your sentence

> I think *(that)* it *(is)* best to be well-prepared for the exam.

Dropping "that" and "is" would be considered to be a stylistic choice rather than a grammatical error.

Comment: So, all of the following are grammatically correct? (1) "I think **that** it **is** best to be well-prepared for the exam"; (2) "I think it **is** best to be well-prepared for the exam"; (3) "I think **that** it best to be well-prepared for the exam"; (4) "I think it best to be well-prepared for the exam".

Comment: #3 is not grammatically correct @Quelqu'un And the most common version in everyday spoken English is "I  think **it's** best to be well-prepared for the exam."

Comment: Also possible is "I think it best **that** one be well-prepared for the exam".