# "She feels it is unsafe" and "she feels it unsafe"

Tags: sentence-construction

I have a question about the phrases "feels it is unsafe to ..." and "feels it unsafe to ..."

When you are talking about someone who is of the opinion that letting children play outside by themselves isn't safe, I think you can say

> She feels **it is** unsafe to let children play outside without
> supervision.

My question is, if you omit "is" in the previous sentence and say the next sentence instead, is it still grammatically acceptable?

> She feels **it** unsafe to let children play outside without
> supervision.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I think it strange that .." -- is the phrase correct or does it miss a verb before 'it'?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/198621/i-think-it-strange-that-is-the-phrase-correct-or-does-it-miss-a-verb-bef) Also [What's wrong in the sentence: “I think it best to be well-prepared for the exam”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/100761/)

Comment: I think the questions are about the same construction. Thank you for the links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are similar constructions where it is common to omit '*to be*' for example:

- She considers it *to be* unsafe.
- She considers it unsafe.
- I think it *is* unwise to do so.
- I think it unwise to do so.

The same rule should apply to your example, although whether or not it will sound natural is another matter. It doesn't sound quite natural to me, as a native British English speaker, and you might be safer leaving the verb in.

Comment: This Canadian agrees it doesn't sound natural.