# Do you think it right vs Do you think it's right

Tags: difference, ellipsis, syntax

When to use either of these sentences:

- **Do you think it right** that Nicole didn't get the job?
- **Do you think it's right** to do that?

I took the first sentence from my grammar book (Oxford Grammar) and made up the second. I'm curious about whether they are differently used or perhaps even have different meaning if they are used in one context.

Comment: Related: [What's wrong in the sentence: "I think it best to be well-prepared for the exam"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/100761/9161)

Answer (score 1):

*Do you think it right that ...* is common, but slightly formal.

However, *Do you think it's right that  ...* is ambiguous, where the first isn't.

The first is asking whether you think that it is fair, appropriate, just, that Nicole didn't get the job.

The second can have this meaning, but can also be asking for confirmation: Is it really true that she didn't get the job?

Answer (score 0):

Do you think it right// that Nicole didn't get the job?

Do you think// it's right that Nicole didn't get the job?

To think something right or wrong is idiomatic in English.

Also, it is idiomatic in English to say: that something is right or wrong using a dummy subject: **It's right** that x, **it's wrong** that x.

Answer (score -1):

They feel quite similar. I have a feeling that the second form may be more common but have nothing to back it up with. Perhaps someone could come up with a better explanation.

Comment: You may want to review the discussion on [meta] about [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117/9161). If you all you have is a feeling and you don't actually know why or aren't confident your feeling is correct, you may want to just leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you Colleen. I'll bear that in mind.